# Recommended settings and setup for Windows Server 2008 R2 Terminal Services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, terminal

What are the recommended settings for a terminal server?

I have a group of up to 300 persons (they are working shifts, so I guess 100-120 on  at same time is unthinkable) who is going to access a terminal server.

The services given on the terminal services server is Internet and Outlook.They will also have access to shared network spaces like their own homespace, shared spaces and some printers.

I was planning to install the terminal services server on vmware-server.

What are the recommended settings for the "hardware"? How many CPU's do I need? How much diskspace do you recommend?

What is the recommended setup for a server like this?

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a good setup?

The plan is that when accessing this server, no data can be transferred back to the client.

Thank in advance.

LM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is about as nice as I can be without expanding out the F in RTFM.  Microsoft has guides for this stuff.

[Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services Planning and Design Guide: Use this guide from Solution Accelerators to plan your Terminal Services infrastructure.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448619)

Comment: This is about the best answer such a vague question deserves, I'd vote it up except I've used all of today's votes.

Comment: I've got some left.

Comment: Thank you kindly, being a wiseass is in my blood, hence the day job in IT.  Haha.

Comment: Thanks alot! I googled terminal services windows server 2008 rec but didnt get any good results up. This would hopefully help me. RTFM is always a good thing, except for when I can't find it...And since I have other things in my workday than googling stuff, I posted on the Internet. An joy, behold, under an hour later an aswer is on my screen.

Comment: Also this link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca837962-4128-4680-b1c0-ad0985939063 Capacity Planning for RD Session Host and Microsoft RemoteFX in Windows Server 2008 R2 with SP1